# Rosjava "reinit"

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want change names of topic during running application. I need something like reinit. Just again execute subscriber/publisher but with different topics.

Thank's lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57822/rosjava-%22reinit%22/) by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-03-11**:
This can be what are you looking for. http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/relay

**Comment by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on 2013-03-11**:
Thank you, but I'm afraid that this is not what I'm looking, I need to call the change programmatically in rosjava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think I understand the issue. Just create a new publisher/subscriber for the new topic?

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0